# Improved Way Make sentence using Ruby Hashes

Tags: ruby

I am creating a hash that contain data related to Name, Age, Hometown, and Favorite Food. I am taking that information and then making a sentence out of it. I have successfully got my code to work, yet I wonder if their is a way to do it that is shorter.

Here is my code:

```
person = {"Name" => "Randy", "Age" => 28, "Hometown" => "Jamesville", 
"Favorite Food" => "Chicken"}

puts "I am #{person.fetch("Name")}. I am #{person.fetch("Age")}-years-old. 
I'm from #{person.fetch("Hometown")} and my favorite food is #
{person.fetch("Favorite Food")}"
```

Which will print

```
I am Randy. I am 28-years-old. I'm from Jamesville and my favorite food is 
Chicken.
```

Comment: Right now your code is clear in what it does. How do you benefit from less code? Less code != Better code. You want code to be clear and maintainable. If you sacrifice that to save a few lines of code (or in this case: characters of code), you are only going to give your future self (or worse, someone else) problems when they need to maintain or change your code.

Comment: You should post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: True Dbz, I had not considered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the `Hash` keys symbols e.g.

```
person = {name: "Randy", 
          age: 28, 
          hometown: "Jamesville", 
          favorite_food: "Chicken"}
```

You could use [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)  instead e.g.

```
sentence = "I am %{name}. I am %{age}-years-old.
       I'm from %{hometown} and my favorite food is %{favorite_food}"
sprintf sentence, person
#=>  "I am Randy. I am 28-years-old.\nI'm from Jamesville and my favorite food is Chicken"
```

or you could use [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25)

```
puts sentence % person
# I am Randy. I am 28-years-old.
#       I'm from Jamesville and my favorite food is Chicken
#=> nil
```

both of these methods rely on symbolized keys though (which by the way is the preferred syntax for a `Hash`)